# .NET DateTime picker flat style

Tags: .net, winforms

In .NET 3.0, most controls have a "flat" style. Apparently, the date picker doesn't have such a style but all the other controls in the form are set as flat. How can I make the date picker flat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding of the datetime picker is that it is limited to what is built into the system.  In other words, it inherited it's limitations from the Shell.  Here is FAQ link that explains [DateTimePicker FAQ entry](http://windowsclient.net/blogs/faqs/archive/2006/05/18/why-doesn-t-the-datetimepicker-control-support-the-flat-style.aspx).

I like to use the  [DotNetBar components](http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/) for quite a while with great success.  Amongs other control, it offers a datetime picker that solves many of the issues with the standard control.

Comment: I'd also like to recommend the DevExpress WinForms controls:
<http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Editors/whatsnew.xml>