# How to make DateTimePicker's checkbox flat?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to make the `DateTimePicker`'s checkbox appear flat?

**EDIT**

Based on the link below, I added the following code in the `OverrideDropDown` method:

```
if (this.ShowCheckBox)
{
    ButtonState state = this.Checked ? ButtonState.Checked : ButtonState.Inactive;

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(3, 3, CheckBoxWidth, this.Height - 6);
    ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(g, rect, ButtonState.Flat | state);
}
```

However, the checkbox is not being drawn flat.

Comment: What does flat mean? any example?

Comment: This link might give some suggession and help -

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6664/DateTimePicker-appears-flat

Comment: I understood.. Now looking for solution. Update you once I have any success!!!

Comment: Checked this link?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225441/net-datetime-picker-flat-style